# References request: vector representations of Lie superalgebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-superalgebras

Are there some references of fundamental representations of Lie superalgebras (in particular for the Lie superalgebra $sl(m|n)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for instance

Manin, Yuri I. Gauge field theory and complex geometry

or

Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians